# If that or that condition not met, do that

Tags: javascript

I have 3 input files on a form. I want to `disable` the submit if the file type does not match with jpeg, gif, png, bmp or pdf file extensions, or if the file size is greater than 2mb. I have both conditions working.

My problem is described as follows: A user submits an upload with a rar, the submit got disabled, that works. Also on the next input file, the user submits a file greater than 2mb, the submit is still disabled, that's ok. But, when the user changes that file with a file less than 2MB, the submit got ENABLED. However, the first input (with the rar file) isn't updated. **It doesn't recheck all the three input files again**!!!

So, I want to make the condition in such a way that all of the inputs need to be good to enable the submit, not only one of them.

I tried with `if (x || y)`, but that didn't work. You can see a live demo [here](https://www.fundacioncb.es/beca-ofertada-cocemfe-badajoz/).

```js
function ValidateSize(file) {
  var FileSize = file.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024; // in MB
  var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf', 'bmp'];
  if (FileSize > 2) {
    alert('El archivo excede los 2MB. Prueba a enviarlo con menor tamaño o no podrás enviar la solicitud.');
    // $(file).val(''); //for clearing with Jquery
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
  }
  if ($.inArray($(file).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
    alert("Solo estos formatos son soportados");
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="cv-becario" class="ewd-otp-file-input" onchange="ValidateSize(this)" type="file" value="" required="">

<input name="certificado-de-notas-becario" class="ewd-otp-file-input" onchange="ValidateSize(this)" type="file" value="" required="">

<input name="titulo-becario" class="ewd-otp-file-input" onchange="ValidateSize(this)" type="file" value="" required="">
```

Comment: first, you could use `<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />`

Comment: @Dementic This adds an improved UX, and I too would recommend it, but it should be noted, that this only provides a suggestion to the OS and does nothing to stop a user from uploading a non accepted file.

Comment: @JohnPavek agreed. on the other hand, the task the OP tries to achieve was done a billion times and he'd be better of not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the validity of all of them before enabling/disabling the button.

I would modify the function to take in the element and return `true/false` instead.

Then rather than use inline `onchange` use a jQuery event listener and do something like the following:

```js
var $fileInputs = $('.ewd-otp-file-input').change(function() {
  // filter collection of valid inputs
  var $validInputs = $fileInputs.filter(function() {
    return ValidateSize(this)
  });
  // if lengths match then all are valid
  var isValid = $fileInputs.length === $validInputs.length;
  // enable/disable based on all valid or not
  $("#submit").prop("disabled", !isValid);

});

// function probably needs some fine tuning
function ValidateSize(file) {
   // if empty input is valid ??
   if(!file.files.length){
     return true;
   }

  var FileSize = file.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024; // in MB
  var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf', 'bmp'];
  if (FileSize > 2) {
    console.log('Over 2 meg')
    return false
  } else {
    if ($.inArray($(file).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
      console.log("Solo estos formatos son soportados");
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="cv-becario" class="ewd-otp-file-input" onchange="ValidateSize(this)" type="file" value="" required=""><br>

<input name="certificado-de-notas-becario" class="ewd-otp-file-input" onchange="ValidateSize(this)" type="file" value="" required=""><br>

<input name="titulo-becario" class="ewd-otp-file-input" onchange="ValidateSize(this)" type="file" value="" required=""><br>

<input name="enviar" id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"><br>
```

Rather than using `alert()` a little extra work in the function would let you add/remove error messages for each of those inputs

Comment: A runnable demo with html code included like the one in the OP would be nice.

Comment: @UdoE. Feel free to add the extra html needed and turn this into a snippet. To be honest I don't mind testing basic UI code for answers but am not interested in spending the time to do the debugging for multiple file inputs with various file types. My answer is a solid guide that can be tweaked and expanded on by OP

Comment: I'm trying to make custom error messages, I inserted $('.ewd-otp-file-input').after('<p>Mayor de 2MB.</p>'); after if (FileSize > 2) { but It insert the error on all the 3 inputs, not only on the previously uploaded file, how I can insert the message only on the previously uplodaded file input only? Thanks.

Comment: In the function use `$(file).after('<p>Mayor de 2MB.</p>');` ... `$(file)` is the current instance of `$('.ewd-otp-file-input')`